# Unable to get isDisabled() to work in Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I need to check that a button is disabled (checking for a last page of a table). There are two with the same `id` (top and bottom of the table).

```
const nextPageButtons = await this.page.$$('button#_btnNext'); // nextPageButtons.length is 2, chekced via console.log
const nextPageButtonState = await nextPageButtons[0].isDisabled();
```

But when I do the above I get: *elementHandle.isDisabled: Unable to adopt element handle from a different document*.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Did you try `this.page.isDisabled('button#_btnNext')`? It will check the first one.

Comment: More an observation than an answer, but if you are in control of the page content you should get the duplicated IDs fixed as the ID should be unique

Comment: @sahmeepee we don't, it's generated by third party library

Comment: @hardkoded this works, but I want to learn and understand this.. according to docs page.$$(selector) returns Promise<Array<ElementHandle>>, so nextPageButtons[0] would be that. And elementHandle.isDisabled() returns Promise<boolean>. So why would it think this ElementHandle is "from different document"?

Comment: Are you sure that your page is not changing in between? maybe between the first call and the second you have elements with the same ID but those are not the same element you got before.

Comment: @hardkoded looks like i'd need to do `const xxx = await nextPageButtons[0];` then `const state = await xxx.isDisabled();`

Comment: The current answer using $$ is *outdated and discouraged* from playwright team. See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77140217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this works:

```
const nextPageButtons = await this.page.$$('button#_btnNext');
const nextPageButton1 = await nextPageButtons[0];
const nextPageButton1State = await nextPageButton1.isDisabled();
```

Comment: This looks a bit off, shouldn't that last line be `await nextPageButton1.isDisabled();`

Comment: your variables are inaccurate in your answer

Comment: Please beware that the use of page.$$ is discouraged and may be it will be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use of `page.$$` is [discouraged](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-query-selector-all) per playwright docs.

> #### WHY?
>
> Because it's static , once defined it stays the same
> throughout the test even though in between test page may refresh
> or re- loaded for any reason and the element definition may become
> stale which may cause the classic "[Stale element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/StaleElementReference)"
> issue.People coming from [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) world will recognize it instantly.

Use locator-based [page.locator()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-locator) [toBeDisabled](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-disabled) method instead.

#### WHY?

> *The biggest difference between the Locator and ElementHandle is that the ElementHandle points to a particular element, while Locator
> captures the logic of how to retrieve an element.*
>
> This happens because [locator](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator) definitions are  *[evaluated lazily](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)* only when an action is performed like 'click' using them instead of at the time of declaring the locator which makes it truly dynamic as now even if the pages gets refreshed or re- loaded and an action is performed using one of those locators will not affected as its definition will be evaluated only when it's used in 'action' so you will never encounter stale element reference exception error.

> Even if you go back to previous page and come back , any locator  still works as is.

Example:

```
const locator = page.locator('yourLocator');
await expect(locator).toBeDisabled();
```

Comment: It would be helpful for you to elaborate on why. You can use `page.locator(...)` with a css selector in just the same way, and that's also discouraged.

Accessibility is important, but still difficult to achieve for many web frameworks both new and old, when the DOM abstracted too much from the developer. 

As I'm learning the hard way with MudBlazor and Playwright right now.

Comment: I tried to explain it my level best , please let me know if it makes it more clear now.Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thank you, that's super helpful, the locator lazy evaluation advantage over $$, I had no idea about. Now I understand why :) I might be coming to you with more playwright questions! +1

Answer (score 0):

To add on the first accepted answer, we can also do this:

```
  // given
 const saveButton = page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Save' });

// then
 expect(saveButton.isDisabled()).toBeTruthy();
```